# Img as background-image

Tags: html, css, image

Can I make the `img` tag use the `background-image` properties? Like for example, I have these two pages here one has `img` and the other one has `background-image` tag. Notice in responsive version the `img` one squeezes the image, while the background-image one adjusts the image according to the size.

- [Page with `IMG` tag](http://ephysiologix.com/dev/videos)
- [Page with `background-image` tag](http://ephysiologix.com/dev/spirituality-consciousness)

You can find both `img` and `background-image` in `sub-header` div ..

Comment: The links you gave are the same. Or am I just loosing my mind?

Comment: Nope, I did. Fixed em ..

Comment: If I may ask, what's the purpose of your question? `<img>` should be used for a small image that can easily be moved around. A `<div>` with the `background-image` CSS property is usually used for the background of a page or a complete section. At least that's usually the standard.

Comment: Well I am getting the image from php back end. Using background-image doesn't make sense and somehow background-image is working for me. So I want to know if img can be used like background-image

Comment: The short answer is yes. The long answer is yes, but it's not recommended. You can refer to `JDB's` answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This'll sound a bit pedantic, but there are a few reasons for it.

An `<img>` element represents content on the page, something intrinsically important to see and understand. Background images are fluffy stuff to make the site look pretty but their removal would not impact the message.

You are mixing your use-cases. You should go with a background-imaged header in this case because the image isn't intrinsic to the message or content of the page.

Use an `<img>` element when you're displaying a graph, a photo someone took, etc.

Why?

- The browser intentionally treats them differently, as you've noticed, placing a higher priority on showing the content of an `<img>` tag for example. It'll attempt to stretch the image to fit by default, while a background will simply be clipped.
- When the user goes to print the page, it's much easier to remove background images via CSS media queries then it is to hide (the correct) IMG tags.
- Background images also don't take up space in the DOM and cause fewer conflicts with other elements. IMG tags flow in the document and can easily get dislodged from their intended position (creating a lot of extra work to make them stay put).
- Right-clicking a background image doesn't do much. Right-clicking an image gives you image related options, such as downloading or opening the image. This goes along with the theme of the `<img>` tag as content.

There are other reasons, but this all boils down to [semantics](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semantic_HTML). This may not seem like a big deal to you, but that's probably because you don't have a vision impairment (so you don't regularly use a screen reader) and aren't really thinking about web crawlers and the many other systems that attempt to extract *meaning* from the tags you've used.

You will be far better off for many, many reasons if you stop fighting the system and use it the way it was intended. Or, at least, know *why* you're bucking convention before doing so.

Comment: Well even though adding `background-image` css via php backend feels a bit hackish, but I think using it would be much suitable for my situation.  Thanks mate ..